# How to add line numbers to a program listing/code?

Tags: numbering, verbatim

How do I copy code in to latex to get a result which looks like this:

[image]

...Without the red bars of course. I don't know how to get the numbering on the left side when I compile LaTeX. Using `\verbatim` only gives me the code.

**Update:** Having the code colored as it would appear in Matlab is necessary.

Comment: `\usepackage{listings}` and then `\begin{lstlisting}your code here \end{lstlisting}`. `texdoc listings` for more info

Comment: @cmhughes Do I need to use verbatim when I paste my code?

Comment: nope, shouldn't do- have a look at the documentation  for more examples :)

Comment: I feel the urge to comment on using nested loops in matlab :P

Comment: @percusse It's an example of non-optimized code. Worse case scenario.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

For my Master thesis I was writing a lot of code in MatLab.  In order to have it "pretty printed" I used the same package as @cmhughes mentioned.  It looks like this (at the preamble):

```
\usepackage{listings} %For code in appendix
\lstset
{ %Formatting for code in appendix
    language=Matlab,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    showstringspaces=false,
    tabsize=1,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
}
```

Then, when you want to include your code file, just use `\lstinputlisting`.  Continuing with the example:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Matlab]{./Code/calc_error.m}
```

I particularly loved this because it allowed me to change my code in MatLab in the folder itself and I didn't have to update it in LaTeX, since I was pointing directly to the file and not the code per se.

The result will be something like this:

[image: Code Example using <code>\usepackage{listings}</code> and setting it up with <code>\lstset</code>]

Of course, you can always play with `\lstset` in order to get what you want, as explained in [the documentation](http://mirrors.fe.up.pt/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)

Comment: You can write `\lstinputlisting{./Code/calc_error.m}` since you have already specified `language=matlab` in your `\lstset`.

Comment: For matlab `mcode` does pretty well.

Comment: How to move the code to right in order to line numbers will not on the left margin?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need code highlighting then the `fancyvrb` package will do. I don't use `matlab`, but for purposes of demonstration, suppose you have a file named `yourfile.m`, then the following code will give you left-side numbering. `VerbatimInput{yourfile.m}` inputs your file.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{%
fontsize=\small,
numbers=left
}

\begin{document}
\VerbatimInput{yourfile.m}
\end{document}
```

Another option is the [`minted`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted). It internally uses `fancyvrb` and uses the  `Pygments` library of `python` for syntax highlighting. Try the following example, replacing `yourfile.m` with your actual file. You have to compile with `-shell-escape` option enabled. Read the manual regarding the installation of the `Pygments` library.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\newmintedfile{matlab}{
linenos=TRUE,
fontsize=\small,
}
\usemintedstyle{trac}

\begin{document}
\matlabfile{yourfile.m}
\end{document}
```