# Listings package in Latex with line numbers for arxiv

Tags: code, arxiv

I'm including some code in a paper submission to arxiv (I assume to prevent galley proofs from being uploaded as discussed here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/49386/why-does-arxiv-not-allow-numbered-lines-in-submissions). However, I used the Listings package in Latex and was rejected by the automod because line numbers are not allowed.  For completeness, here is the Latex code for the Listings package from [How to add line numbers to a program listing/code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106770/how-to-add-line-numbers-to-a-program-listing-code):

```
\usepackage{listings} %For code in appendix
\lstset
{ %Formatting for code in appendix
    language=Matlab,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    showstringspaces=false,
    tabsize=1,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
}
```

I think the code is more useful with the line numbers since it can go for a few lines in this particular case. So, I'd like to keep including them. I tried changing the `numbers=left` to `numbers=right` and changing the `numbersep=5pt` default to something to keep the numbers in the box, but automod still rejected it.

Has anyone else found an issue with arxiv on this? Did you find a way to put line numbers into the code snippet? Is there a better package or way to still have line numbers but not have them show up for arxiv's moderation?

Comment: If you can find an arxiv paper that that contains numbered code lines, then you may learn how it achieved this from its source.

Comment: I just used line numbers for code in code listings, and it worked. I got no error from arxiv. It might be they only allow line numbers for code listing, but not line number for the paper itself.

Answer (score 1):

arXiv doesn't allow line numbers in the **full text**, and we don't care if it's within code blocks, or lines of a table, etc., these *are* more useful with them in place.

This error in arXiv is sometimes a false-positive, so I suggest reaching out through our official [support channels](https://arxiv.org/help/contact) if you are still having difficulties. Remember to include your submit-id so that we can find your submission's source more quickly.